# Enterprise App on iOS 12 Won’t Verify

Tags: applications, enterprise, 3rd-party

I have an enterprise app on my iPhone, and it states it will be verified until it is deleted. But today, all of a sudden it stopped working and refuses to re-verify. How can I fix this? [image]

Answer (score 2):

The text actually does not state that it will be verified until it is deleted. Rather it says that the certificate will be *trusted* until the apps are deleted. That is different.

The signature on the app which is checked via the certificate (amongst other things) expires after a set time. You'll need to connect to the internet to verify the app again.

If that doesn't work, you'll need to contact your employer who published the app.